# passenger-status not showing memory usage?

Tags: nginx, passenger

I am running nginx/passenger on Ubuntu 16.04, and it is working fine, but for some reason `passenger-status` is showing zero for both the cpu and the memory. It makes no difference if I run it with `sudo` or not. Has anyone else seen this before?

[image: passenger status]

Comment: What is the output of `sudo /usr/bin/passenger-config validate-install` and `sudo /usr/sbin/passenger-memory-stats` ?

Comment: Are you running in a docker environment and is ps installed? We get those stats from the ps command.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: ps is install - it is not running under docker

Comment: @TarunLalwani passenger-memory-stats *does* include the memory information. Validate install says "Everything looks good."

Comment: What does the output of `ps -p $PID1,$PID2 -o pid,ppid,%cpu,rss,vsize,pgid,uid,command` look like where `$PID1,$PID2` is a comma separated list of pids from the `passenger-status` command?

Comment: @CamdenNarzt `6077 19726  0.0  1820   9676 19726  1000 /bin/bash /var/www/app/_ruby /usr/`

Comment: Well, you can see that the cpu use is being reported as 0.0%, so that much checks out.